# Can cURL DIRLISTONLY distinguish between files and directories?

Tags: php, curl

This will print a list of the contents of a directory. However, the directory contains both images and subdirectories, and I can see no way to distinguish between them.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/Images/');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, TRUE);
$r = curl_exec($c);
echo $r;
```

Searching reveals [someone else asking the same question](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2016-02/0002.html) on a cURL mailing list, but I cannot find an answer.

Ideally, I’d like to receive the list of contents as a PHP object or array, rather than as text which I then need to parse again. Filenames are *unlikely* to contain linebreaks, so I can probably split on those, but that feels fragile.

What I actually *want* to do is to download the entire directory with all its contents.

Comment: So if `$r` contains list of dirs and files, than check if item has extension. If extension is not enough than you need to check mime-type of each file

Comment: *What I actually want to do to download the entire directory with all its contents* ...  if possible use ssh to zip the directory and download the zip via curl ... if not .. use fpt_* functions and write your wrapper ... but why did you want to do this?

Comment: I have only FTP access to the remote server, @donald123. And sometimes I'll want to download everything in it, and sometimes I'll just want to read the list of files and download some of them.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Use [FTP Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) Instead. You can fetch list from ftp with [ftp_nlist](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) and check if is file or folder with [ftp_chdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php). This is example form php.net:

```
function ftp_is_dir( $conn_id,  $dir )
{
    if( @ftp_chdir( $conn_id, $dir ) ) {
        ftp_chdir( $conn_id, '/../' );
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

Create php file on the server that says the folder list and file list for you in the requested directory. for example get the list with `domain.com/get-list.php?folder=something/another-folder` and encode your list with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and decode it at your server with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

*this method can work without FTP.*

**Method 3**

You can use [is_dir — Tells whether the filename is a directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some **URL**
> **wrappers**. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which
> wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

Comment: strange that the standard lib hasn't created a class wrapper around those functions yet...

Comment: I have read-only access to this system (which I should have clarified in the question), so Method 2 is out, but the other two look promising. I'll try and see.